# Hyperbolic PDE classification

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Considering the following equation
$$u_t + A u_x = 0,\quad t> 0$$
where
$$ A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & \sin t \\ \sin t & -1 \end{pmatrix} $$
Naturally, the system is hyperbolic if $A$ consist of 2 distinct eigenvalues and $A$ has 2 linearly independent (left) eigenvectors. This much is clear, but I run into problems when finding these eigenvectors, as one of them vanish completely or blows up completely.

For your convenience, here is the eigenvalues:
$$ \lambda = \pm\sqrt{1+\sin^2(t) }$$

So my idea is to linearize $\sqrt{1+\sin^2(t)}$, but I am unsure on how to do this.

Any thoughts?

Comment: When you say 'linearize' you mean $t \sim 0$, right? What's wrong with $\sqrt{1 + \sin^2 t} \sim 1 + \frac{1}{2} \sin^2(t) \sim 1 + \frac{t^2}{2}$?

Comment: Sorry, I see I forgot some details. It is correct now. I also see why linearizing is a bad idea in the first place. Thanks for your response though.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, $A(t) \in \mathbb{R}^{2\times 2}$ is symmetric which implies that it is always diagonalizable [[1]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_matrix#Real_symmetric_matrices), [[2]](http://maecourses.ucsd.edu/%7Emdeolive/mae280a/lecture11.pdf) with real eigenvalues.

However, since you cannot guarantee for all times $t$ that your eigenvalues are distinct (consider $t = k \pi, k \in \mathbb{N}$) your system is not *strictly* hyperbolic.